# I know that MapReduce uses key-value pairs. What exactly are the key and the value in this context?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In MapReduce, I know that the Input Reader translates each record in an input file and sends the parsed data to the mapper in the form of key-value pairs. However, I don't know what exactly what the key and the value represent. I have read many sources, including Apache's documentation and Tutorials Point's section on MapReduce, but I still can't find what they are.

I have 2 guesses:

1) The key represents an identifier for the record (such as an index), and the value represents the actual data.

2) The key represents the node in the cluster that will process that particular record, and the value represents the data of that record.

Am I correct?  If not, please tell me what the right answer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me say for TextInputFormat, which is the default input format for mapreduce.

**Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text.**

You can always refer the API doc.https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html

For any input format implementation, you can just go and verify in the API doc what is the key and value used by that input format. In most cases, the key will the offset and value will be the actual record in the file.